# Spine JS stack routes - undefined params?

Tags: coffeescript, spine.js

I have a basic Spine/coffeescript app and I am trying to get the parameters out of the route that I have set up, by looking at examples of other applications. Here is the basic stack:

```
class Main extends Spine.Stack
  el: "#main"

  controllers:
    sources: Sources

  default: 'sources'

  routes:
    '/sources/:id': 'sources'
```

Here is the sources controller:

```
class Sources extends Spine.Controller
  el: '#something'

  constructor: ->
    super

  active: (params) ->
    super
    @id = params.id
    @refresh()
    @render()
```

However, `params` is undefined when active is called. I am navigating to `/#/sources/soemthing`. Maybe there is something about the sugar in the stack that I don't understand, but the example I've seen seems to just work in this way. Can anyone tell me what is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently the stack always initializes the default controller with no parameters before switching to one of the other controllers, even if you navigate to /#/route/parameter directly. After adding a default controller that does nothing, this problem went away.

```
class Main extends Spine.Stack
  el: "#main"

  controllers:
    home: Home
    sources: Sources

  default: 'home'

  routes:
    '/': 'home'
    '/sources/:zooniverse_id': 'sources'
```

P.S. If you are trying to get Spine help on SO, don't. Go to the SpineJS google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/spinejs